# Scrape Image Url from data-src using css selector

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am pretty new scrapy and here I need some help regarding image url that is in the data-src .... Here is my code....

```
from typing import Text
import scrapy

class SeamsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'seams'
    start_urls = [
        'https://in.seamsfriendly.com/collections/shorts'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title : response.css("#shopify-section-collection-template a::text").extract()
        price : response.css(".Price::text").extract()
        url : response.css("img.data-src::text").extract()
```

I am not getting any output using the above , please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to suffix `::text` for extracting text content from a selector, we have also the suffix `::attr(attribute_name)` for extract the value for a given attribute. In your case, in order to get the content within `data-src`attribute you can use the following selector:

```
response.css("img::attr(data-src)").extract()
```